# How I can run 100 different clint end reports on azure server and check response time of every report.?

Tags: azure, testing, automation, response-time, manual-testing

Am a manual tester and newbie in automation. I need to test the response time of 100 different reports from the azure server to Clint's end. If I go manually It almost takes a day. Suggest a solution How I can get results in a short time with automation testing?

Answer (score 0):

*You can use application insights*
[image]

*refer this document for more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/tutorial-performance*